# Is there any way to get LinkedIn to return SSL resources?

Tags: linkedin-api

Facebook supports the parameter `return_ssl_resources` for its Graph API. Is there anything similar for LinkedIn's REST API? The idea is to get it to return HTTPS URLs for pictures and avoid the browser's mixed protocol warnings in my app, which is SSL-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was recently (Dec 2012) added to the LinkedIn API. You can now append "`secure=true`" to fetch SSL versions of profile pictures.

```
GET http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url;secure=true)
```

[Check Source Here](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/20464#comment-20464)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the only solution right now is to replace `http://media.linkedin.com/` with `https://www.linkedin.com/` in the image URLs. This is being advocated by LinkedIn's own staff ([1](https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2268) and [2](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/ssl-profile-picture-url-https)) until they introduce proper support in their API.